# Keyboard not showing up with .focus() when app' s onResume() [React-Native]

Tags: react-native, keyboard, onfocus

I have quite a tricky situation. I've got an "hided" `TextInput` (on my screen) where the value of this TextInput is affected to a basical `<Text/>` within my View.
More or less structured like that :

```
<View>
   <Text>{this.state.value}</Text>
   <TextInput ref={ref => this.textInputRef = ref} 
              style={{position:"absolute"}} 
              onChange((text)=>this.setState({value:text})) /> 
</View>
```

When my `View` showed up for the first time, the keyboard is displayed, and everything works well.

However, if the user hide the app, meaning the `AppState` of the application becomes `background` (entered background), and then open again the app. The Keyboard's `blurred()`, and trigger `this.textInputRef.focus()` doesn't works. No way to display again the Keyboard, I tried everythings, even if the callback methods are called, the Keyboard never show up again.

Any ideas about how we could handle this case ?

Thank's for the help